# How to make the mouselook same speed for all controllers?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm developing a game using the new input system, I tested the `mouselook` it worked fine using the keyboard. but when connected `x-box controller` the `mouselook` is very slow unlike on PC!

[mouse look inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ItMD1.png)

[Input Action](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BYaEz.png)

`Mouselook` class:

```cs
    public class MouseLook : MonoBehaviour
    {
        [SerializeField] float sensitivityX = 8f;
        [SerializeField] float sensitivityY = 0.05f;
        float mouseX, mouseY;
        [SerializeField] Transform playerCamera;
        [SerializeField] float xClamp = 85f;
        float xRotataion = 0f;
     private void Update()
        {         transform.Rotate(Vector3.up, mouseX * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
            xRotataion -= mouseY;
            xRotataion = Mathf.Clamp(xRotataion, -xClamp, xClamp);
            Vector3 targetRotation = transform.eulerAngles;
            targetRotation.x = xRotataion;
            playerCamera.eulerAngles = targetRotation;
    
        }
        public void ReceiveInput(Vector2 mouseInput) 
        {
            mouseX = mouseInput.x * sensitivityX;
            mouseY = mouseInput.y * sensitivityY;
        }
```

`InputManager` class:

```cs
     private void Awake() 
      {
            controls = new PlayerControls(); 
            groundMovement = controls.GroundMovement;
    groundMovement.MouseX.performed += ctx => mouseInput.x = ctx.ReadValue<float>();
    groundMovement.MouseY.performed += ctx => mouseInput.y = ctx.ReadValue<float>();
    }
     private void Update()
        {
            movement.ReceiveInput(horizontalInput);
            mouseLook.ReceiveInput(mouseInput); 
        }
```

How to make the `mouselook` for x and y constant for all kinds of controllers?